# regex match for booking reference in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a booking reference field I want to match the regex with a string that is 8 characters starting with 3 letters, 4 numbers with a hyphen in between, I know how to include the hyphen and letters and numbers but have never limited it to a certain amount for each part.

I am new to regex and find it very intriguing indeed but I am struggling with the syntax for this one. An example would be `abc-1234` being valid.

I have tried this:

```
    if (id == "email"){                           //Allow valid email
      pattern = /^.+?\@.*?$/  ;                  // test the value against an appropriate regular expression 
     failmessage ="Only valid email addresses are permitted here";
    }

    //test booking reference
    if (id == "bookref"){                         // Allow valid booking reference
      pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]{3}-{1}[0-9]{4}$/ ;      // test the value against an appropriate regular expression 
      failmessage="Only valid booking references are permitted here"; // Output error message with invalid input
    }
```

I know it's wrong as I have tested it but I can't come up with anything my email field is fine, I just have never had to be specific about the amount, can anyone help?

Comment: Other than not needing `{1}` (a literal character is assumed to represent only one character by default), your regex looks fine to me. It should match a string that starts with 3 letters, continues with a single hyphen, and ends with 4 numbers. NOTE: Because you're using `^` and `$`, the ENTIRE string must match this; if you want to match anywhere inside the string, omit those starting and ending anchors.

Comment: Adding an update: I just tested your regex against your example string of `abc-1234` and it matches correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried it on regex101 and got no match to my string, where did you test it? if you don't mind me asking.

Comment: I just ran it in the browser's dev console: `/^[a-zA-Z]{3}-{1}[0-9]{4}$/.test('abc-1234')` returns true. (It also returns true without the redundant `{1}` bit.)

Comment: I just tested on Regex101 and got a match as well?

Comment: Thanks folks got it working a little late back I know, silly syntax error all along in regex101 by me.

Answer (score 0):

your pattern looks correct. I have modified little bit. Try this one :

```
/[a-zA-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}/g
```